# How do you implement a responding shell script in a Kotlin web service coroutines request?

Tags: kotlin, concurrency, race-condition, kotlin-coroutines, processbuilder

I created a web service with spring boot 2 and Kotlin to access same unix scripts and other programs of a certain server via a process builder. The response messages shall contain the stdout of the shell script I use. But I have problems with the coroutines in Kotlin. When I use *process.waitFor()* this is a blocking function. How can you use a dedicated thread(-pool) to track the external processes and suspend the coroutines for that time?
In the following code snippet you see how I get the return code of a shell script and the stdout information of it:

```
    val process = ProcessBuilder(cmd)
        .redirectErrorStream(true)
        .start()
    val exitCode = process.waitFor()

    return CmdResult(
        exitCode,
        process.inputStream
    )
```

I failed with the following trial, because I did not get the stdout information and did not know how to get the result out of the scope to use it as a return type:

```
val dispatcher = newFixedThreadPoolContext(4, "myPool")
launch(dispatcher) {
    val process = ProcessBuilder(listOf(cmdScript))
                .redirectErrorStream(true)
                .start()
    val exitCode = process.waitFor()
            
    CmdResult(
        exitCode,
        process.inputStream
    )
}.join()
```

Comment: You can use `async(dispatcher) { ... }` and then call `await()` on it to get the result. A task created by `launch` is more of a "fire&forget" task that doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can use top level function [`withContext`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/with-context.html) to return from a coroutine:

```kotlin
val dispatcher = newFixedThreadPoolContext(4, "myPool")

val result = withContext(dispatcher) {
    val process = ProcessBuilder(listOf(cmdScript))
                .redirectErrorStream(true)
                .start()
    val exitCode = process.waitFor()
            
    CmdResult(
        exitCode,
        process.inputStream
    )
}
```

Comment: In the end I could even reuse my old sources just with surrounding the withContext method:

```
val cmdResult =
                withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
                    runCommand(listOf(cmdScript))
                }
```